# Multiple Binding targets if one value is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'd like to bind a `Textblock.Text` to a class property which I've done, but when this value is null, I'd like a new property to be used and if that's null, then a default value to be set. I thought this is what PriorityBinding is for?

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="Property1"/>
            <Binding Path="Property2"/>
            <Binding Source="---"/>
    </PriorityBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Comment: This is just a suggestion, I haveb't tried whether it works, but you could try with style and triggers, so if Property1 value = null, then have a setter, setting text binding to property2

Answer (score 3):

`null` is a valid value for the `Textblock.Text` property, so it will never use any of the other bindings.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding(v=vs.110).aspx):

> PriorityBinding lets you associate a binding target (target) property
>   with a list of bindings. The first binding that returns a value
>   successfully becomes the active binding.
>
> A binding returns a value successfully if:
>
> 1. The path to the binding source resolves successfully.
> 2. The value converter, if any, is able to convert the resulting value.
> 3. The resulting value is valid for the target property.
>
> The value DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is not considered a successful
>   return value.

---

You may add a binding converter that returns `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` when the property value is `null`:

```
public class NullValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value ?? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` is something that you can't return from a string property which is what the type of binding we typically use for `Text` property.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel is correct. `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` is an object which is not a valid return type for a string. So the question still remains.

Comment: I guess the "correct" way is to use a binding converter. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, converter is the way to go. Was about to write and answer. Not there is no need to do as you have it already. I'd write it as `return value ?? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;`

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an Exception will cause the property to not be resolved, thus allowing the `PriorityBind`ing to filter on to the next bind.

Comment: From the MSDN article on [Exception Throwing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229030(v=vs.100).aspx): *Do not use exceptions for normal flow of control ...*